# What design pattern should I use for WebServices initialization?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am using SOAP which initialization takes some time so I don't want to this with every request. As far as I know singleton is not proper pattern for this situation. I use static factory method for this which is mentioned in What are static factory methods in Java?
Is it good practice?

```
public class ServiceConnection {
    public static final int MAX_CONNS = 5;

    private static int totalConnections;

    public static Set<Service> serviceIterator = new HashSet<>();

    private ServiceConnection(){
        totalConnections++;
    }

    public static Service getService(){
        if(totalConnections < MAX_CONNS){
            Service service = new Service();
            serviceIterator.add(service);
            return service;
        }else{
            return serviceIterator.iterator().next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that the `Singleton` pattern is not proper?

Comment: @npinti because as far as I know singleton should be used when there should be exactly one instance of specific object. Having multi instances of Service is not problem for me. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You could use a singleton object to manage a pool of services.

Comment: This looks a lot like a problem for Registry Pattern to solve...